# EasyAPNS not registering device to database for app that's now from AppStore

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using easyapns to handle the Push Notifications for an app. Devices registered fine to the database while in development or adhoc mode, when the app was run on the device (iPhone), the device would register without error. I got the app approved on the app store, but now any new device will not register!

Looking forward for an answer any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you used the development certificate with push notifications in the app that was approved?

Comment: Yes I did, strange is that in the developer and production mode, it works well.

Comment: I recreated the push notification certificate for apns but no positive result, development & production works well, but the app from the AppStore doesn't work, I don't know why this happens.